# Explicit wait is not working in jmeter webdriver sampler

Tags: selenium, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Below is my code. It is running fine when I remove wait command from code but wnen I am adding wait in below code it started showing the error like :
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: null has no such function "visibilityOfElementLocated" in  at line number 13
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)

Code -
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
var search1 = WDS.args[0]
var pkg=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium) //import java selenium package`import java selenium package`
var support_ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)`import webdriver`
var ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(120))
var timeunit = java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search']")).clear()
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search']")).sendKeys(search1)
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//td/img[@id='search']")).click()
wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//td[text()='224' and @class='SwsCount']")))`This wait command is not working`
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

I am expecting to use explicit wait in webdriver sampler. I am using apache-jmeter 5.5 version

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not readable hence we're not able to provide a comprehensive answer.

This error:

> null has no such function "visibilityOfElementLocated"

means that (most probably) your `pgk.ExpectedConditions` is [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null) so I would recommend revisiting your code and checking where you're defining this `pkg` variable.

Example simple code showing how to use Explicit Waits in WebDriver Sampler with JavaScript:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('https://duckduckgo.com')


var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(5))
var by = org.openqa.selenium.By.id("search_form_input_homepage")
var condition = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by)
var element = wait.until(condition)

element.sendKeys('jmeter')

element.submit()

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Also be aware that your approach is not very future-proof as [Nashorn engine has been removed from JDK 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) therefore you won't be able to use `javascript` language with newer versions of Java. It's better consider migrating to [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), moreover it's [the recommended scripting option since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Comment: Thanks I could fix the code. Since I am not familiar with the groovy language, I have started using javascript. But I will definitely try to use groovy. thank you once again